# angular.dart NgTwoWay and NgAttr deprecated?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have just started using Angular dart and Im going through the online tutorial with examples, and DartEditor is currently striking out NgAttr and NgTwoWay saying they are deprecated, is this the case? and if so what are they being replaced with? the auto docs don't say.

Comment: see also https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/929 (contains not much information yet) and a similar quesition here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23150818

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`NgAttr`, `NgOneWay`, `NgTwoWay`, etc. were marked deprecated in preparation to the new `bind-*` syntax, which is not implemented, yet. So deprecation is arguably a bit premature, since there's no action for users to take, but I guess it is a first warning of the impending major breaking change.

Comment: Maybe it would be a good idea to start deprecating things only when the replacement is ready ;-)

Comment: Well, imho, "deprecated bits" need an annotation like:

 ... @deprecated( "refactor, implementation is unreliable" )

Answer (score 4):

As of AngularDart 0.13.0, these attributes are no longer marked as deprecated.

As Pavel pointed out, the deprecation was premature. We may re-deprecate them when we have a better way of doing things, but for now you can use them without that nagging feeling that you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

There is a new milestone for [bind-* syntax](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues?milestone=21&page=1&state=open) which has issues discussing these changes, it may not be actually removed until 1.0 is what I feel.