# Now that Controller is deprecated, what do I use instead?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have two top level controllers, and now that `Controller` is deprecated, I'm wondering how to convert them to whatever it is they need to be.

Answer (score 5):

[In the answer of a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23150818/why-is-controller-deprecated-in-angulardart-0-10-0) it was already mentioned that even though `Controller` is already deprecated there is no replacement yet but will be before 1.0.

As far as I read from recent issue updates `Template` is planned to become the replacement for `Controller` and `Decorator`/`Directive`. I haven't checked but I think it is not yet shipped in 0.11.0.

My understanding is that `Template` is a combination of `Controller` and `Component` without shadowDOM.

Comment: I am using components with shadowDom:false instead of Controllers. The shadowDOM.js to be used give me stacktraces when compiled to JS in chrome and firefox.

Comment: @Daniel I think components with `shadowDom: false` is what becomes Template (not sure about this though). `shadow_dom.js` is deprecated and known to cause errors - use http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/web_components instead.