# Replacement of Controller in AngularDart

Tags: dart, angular-dart

As `Controller` is deprecated, is there good replacement for it?

I understand, why it was deprecated, but now need to find a replacement for it.

Assuming that I need to publish some functions to HTML (so Decorators couldn't be used), but without any template HTML (so Component couldn't be used).

Moreover, if there is a state, that these functions could use.

Example:

```
<div>
  <div request-sender>First sender:<button ng-click="sender.send()">Send1</button></div>
  <div request-sender>And <button ng-click="sender.send()">Send2</button> - second sender</div>
</div>
```

Code:

```
@Controller(selector:'request-sender') 
class SenderCtrl {
   int counter = 0;
   Http _http;
   SenderCtrl(this._http);
   void send() { counter++;_http.get('someUrl/$counter'); }
}
```

So if I press two times on first button, then clicking to second button will issue request to `someUrl/1` and not `someUrl/3`

Comment: Did you check these questions
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23150818, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23549800

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Controller deprecated in AngularDart 0.10.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23150818/why-is-controller-deprecated-in-angulardart-0-10-0)

Comment: Sure I've checked all questions and issues on github, but didn't found good solution, except Component with template kind of `<div><conent /></div>`, but it looks ugly and adds additional elements.

Comment: I haven't seen any better answers yet but maybe someone else has a good idea.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer in these comments described reason (move context to strict typed objects instead of Map), but there is no solution, with which we can have same functionality. Did you found?

Comment: I know, there is no (not yet a) good answer. But its not considered good practice on SO to ask a question again just because an existing question has not the desired answer.

Comment: @ValentynShybanov You can follow the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/919) that Günter linked in his answer. Once that is closed, an answer should emerge in the next Angular version.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer There is a question "why controllers are deprecated" and it is answered. My question is to find a replacement for them with practical example, that couldn't be covered by any comment or link, provided in previous question. These questions are different - I DO fully understand WHY controllers are deprecated, and now searching answer for another question - HOW to achieve desired functionality without controllers. It is not asking same question.

Comment: @PixelElephant after that issue would be closed, you would be able to provide a single context as root context of application. But in my example, you should have two contex. How single context would help? Also imagine, if sample HTML/Dart code is part of some library, and main application would have own root contex. In this case you couldn't even put sub-contexes as properties of root contex. So solving that issue won't solve described use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at this commit, the examples are changed to reflect the deprecation of the controller:

https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/commit/5f8e27659ffb0140e0c153f8cecd627df273bfd2