# How do I reference the controller in html without using @Controller annotation

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Since the @Controller annotation is deprecated, how do I reference to my controller in html without using @Controller in dart code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Controller deprecated in AngularDart 0.10.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23150818/why-is-controller-deprecated-in-angulardart-0-10-0)

Comment: It is a bit weird that it is deprecated but has no replacement yet. 
See my answer on the linked question for more details (also down to the last comment)